# Не могу получить html код сайта

Tags: c#, webclient

Пытаюсь получить HTML код с сайта 
https://www.rbc.ru/finances/05/01/20...from=from_main
Если выполнить этот код пишет что север не найден 404 хотя все в браузере работает.
В чем может быть проблема и как поправить?

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
  string url = "https://www.rbc.ru/rbcfreenews/5e10c7039a7947e75374330d? 
  utm_source=yxnews&utm_medium=desktop&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fyandex.ru%2Fnews";

  string HtmlCode = client.DownloadString(url);
  Console.WriteLine(HtmlCode);

}
```

Comment: Заголовки отправьте те же, что ваш браузер

Comment: Простите я не понял совета) Можете пример привести?

Comment: `client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "...");`

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо вы мне очень помогли.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решился благодаря добавлению заголовка. Всем огромное спасибо!

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
      client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36");

      string url = "https://www.rbc.ru/rbcfreenews/5e10c7039a7947e75374330d? 
      utm_source=yxnews&utm_medium=desktop&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fyandex.ru%2Fnews";

      string HtmlCode = client.DownloadString(url);
      Console.WriteLine(HtmlCode);
    }
```